# How to make jQuery popup wider than default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on this test page: http://www.problemio.com/test.php

If you click the login link, you can see that it looks nice and neat and fits into the default width.

But if you click on the create-profile link you can see that the popup is too narrow to fit all the form fields and text.

I tried making it wider by giving some style to the containing div like this  but that only made the div wider, but not the popup that opens.

How can I control the styling and the width/height of the popup made by jQuery?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the height and width in the arguments.

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({ height: 530, width: 600 });
```

Take a look at the [options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#options).

Answer (score 3):

you can even change the default width by going to "jqueryui.css"
and change the width property of `.ui-dialog`

```
.ui-dialog { position: absolute; padding: .2em; width: XXXpx; overflow: hidden; }
```

that's less js code everytime you pop a dialog